# Atmega32u4 Pin F0 output is only 3.64V, not 5.00V

Tags: atmega32u4

Unlike F4 which outputs 5.0V, my F0 pin only outputs 3.64V.
Is this normal?

This is my code:

```
DDRF  |= (1 << 0);  // Set F0 to output 
PORTF |= (1 << 0);  // Set F0's internal pull-up
```

I have 2 identical boards and only 1 exhibits this behavior.

Comment: Two **identical** boards, which are _different_? What does that tell you?

Comment: @BruceAbbott nothing different physically. Fw is the same. Yet still different behaviour.

Comment: "nothing different physically" - then the difference must be metaphysical. One of your boards is haunted!

Comment: I guess I am asking if there is special mode for this pin that would result in this output voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion 1: Check your ground connections.

Suggestion 2: Edit your question and show the external circuitry, if any, that's connected between F0 and GROUND, including a fixed resistance between F0 and GROUND that models your voltmeter's input impedance.

Suggestion 3:  Measure / determine the DC output current at pin F0. That output current must not exceed 40 mA. Also, a DIO pin's output voltage is inversely related to its output current: the greater the output current, the lower the output voltage.

Suggestion 4:  Verify you are not exceeding the chip's max rated DC current spec of 200 mA at the VCC power pin--e.g., the combined sum of the output currents at all DIO pins does not exceed, say, 160 mA (see also the chip's ICC electrical spec).

Suggestion 5: Your post doesn't state whether output pin F0 is programmed for logic HIGH output, logic LOW output, or is tri-stated (floating).